# spring AccessDeniedHandler interface don't get called when i have ExceptionHandler of RuntimeException in ControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have implemented the AccessDeniedHandler interface and added the interface to the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and I also have an ExceptionHandler of RuntimeException in my ControllerAdvice.
When I receive accessDeniedException from MethodSecurity, ExceptionHandler calls RuntimeException before running AccessDeniedHandler.

How to call AccessDeniedHandler without deleting ExceptionHandler?

this is my WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    public static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/**";
    public static final String JWT_TOKEN_HEADER_PARAM = "X-Authorization";

    @Value("${payment.gateway.callback-path}")
    private String paymentCallbackPath;


    @Autowired
    private ThingspodAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;


    protected JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        List<String> pathsToSkip = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(paymentCallbackPath));
        SkipPathRequestMatcher matcher = new SkipPathRequestMatcher(pathsToSkip, TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT);
        JwtAuthenticationFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter(matcher, JWT_TOKEN_HEADER_PARAM, authenticationFailureHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().cacheControl().and().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(paymentCallbackPath).permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
    }

}
```

and this is my AccessDeniedHander and ExceptionHandler in ControllerAdvice:

```
@Component
public class ThingspodAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ThingspodAccessDeniedHandler(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
        Object res = buildResponse(accessDeniedException, "You don't have permission to perform this operation!", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, ThingspodErrorCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, request);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), res);
    }
}
```

```
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllUncaughtRuntimeException(
            RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request){
        return buildApiErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ThingspodErrorCode.GENERAL, request);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfortunate limitation of the way Spring Security handles its own exceptions. You can read more about it at the bug report (which was rejected) at Spring Security: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6908#issuecomment-533269673

The only thing to do in this case is to spot Spring Security related exceptions in your ExceptionHandler and rethrow them.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting a error handler, spring will look for the most specific one.

Since you have exception handler for the more general exception (`RuntimeException`) and another one for `AccessDeniedException`.

In that case first exception handler (for handling `RuntimeException`) won't be called when `AccessDeniedException` occurs.

So you could keep exception handler for handling RuntimeExceptions, but you will need to add exception handler for handling `AccessDeniedException` and move logic from `ThingspodAccessDeniedHandler` into that handler method, like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(UnknownHostException.class)
    public void handleUnknownAccessDeniedException(UnknownHostException e, WebRequest request) {
        Object res = buildResponse(accessDeniedException, "You don't have permission to perform this operation!", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, ThingspodErrorCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, request);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), res);
    }



@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllUncaughtRuntimeException(
            RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request){
        return buildApiErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ThingspodErrorCode.GENERAL, request);
    }
```

Comment: This answer is the opposite way round from the problem in the question: the question asks why the _general_ ExceptionHandler handles everything, including AccessDeniedException.

Comment: @altanqa "why the general ExceptionHandler handles everything, including AccessDeniedException" - beacause there is no more specific exception handler registrated in application, that's why. I explained that in answer.